# Javascript- How to pass array to add table row onclick funtion

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick

I have an array and branch_id that I want to pass to javascript add table row with onclick function.

```
var branch_id = 1;
var member_data= [];
    member_data.push({
        phone: 123,
        name: "aaa",
        id: 3,
    });
    member_data.push({
        phone: 456,
        name: "bbb",
        id: 4,
    });
  addrow(branch_id ,member_data)
```

Pass data and array to addrow function, and set array as the parameter in onclick function. When click on the Show button, it will show all the array data

```
function addrow(branch_id, member_data){
   console.log(member_data)//able to read array
   var table = document.getElementById("itemTable");
   var tableRow = table.rows.length;
   var row = table.insertRow(tableRow);
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

   cell1.innerHTML = 
                    '<button type="button" onclick="show_member(member_data)">Show</button>'//this line of show "member_data is not defined"
                    + '<input type="text" name="branch" value="'+branch_id+'">';
}

function show_member(member_data){
    for (var i = 0; i < member_data.length; i++) {
       alert(member_data[i]);
    }
}
```

But I am unable to pass the array to the onclick, it show "member_data is not defined". Isn't possible to pass array to onclick function

Comment: is `member_data` available on console?

Comment: There's a syntax error: `name: bbb,` should be `name: "bbb"`, same for `name: aaa`, they're being interpreted as identifiers, not strings.

Comment: sorry for the mistake, thanks RobG remind, I have update the code

Comment: @daymannovaes at the beginning of the function addrow(branch_id, member_data), I loop and call member_data, the result show, but I pass it to the onclick,then error messagen show

Comment: But depending on the way you are defining the `member_data` variable, it won't be available globally. For example, if this `var member_data` is inside a function, this will not be accessible in to onClick. You must do somethin like `window.member_data = ...` or declare it outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown your complete code, but if you temporarily change `show_member(member_data)` to `show_member("fake data")`, you get an error indicating that `show_member` is not defined, which tells us that the problem is not just that member_data can't be found, but indeed the `show_member` function can't be found either. This tells us that the problem is scope.

I've reorganized your code so that the items that need to be accessible are put into a more persistent scope and the code now runs:

```
<script>

// These variables and functions are being declared in a higher scope than where 
// they will be called from, which makes them accessible to any lower scopes.
var branch_id = 1;
var member_data = [];
member_data.push({
  phone: 123,
  name: "aaa",
  id: 3,
});

member_data.push({
  phone: 456,
  name: "bbb",
  id: 4,
});

function show_member(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    alert(data[i].phone);
  }
}

function addrow(branch_id, member_data) {
  console.log(member_data)//able to read array
  var table = document.getElementById("itemTable");
  var tableRow = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(tableRow);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

  cell1.innerHTML = '<button type="button" onclick="show_member(member_data)">Show</button>'
                    + '<input type="text" name="branch" value="' + branch_id + '">';
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // addrow was declared at a higher scope, so it's accessible here
  // We need to have this function call wait until the DOM is loaded
  // because it needs to scan the DOM for the table elements
  addrow(branch_id, member_data);
});

</script>
```

Comment: it haven go to show_member(), when I click on the button Show, the error message show "member_data is not defined"

Comment: sorry for the mistake, is the member name, i have change the code, it should be name:"aaa" and name:"bbb"

Comment: in the beginning of the addrow function, the array able to read, but when I pass it to onclick="show_member(member_data)", unable to go to show_member function it show "member_data is not defined"